# Nvidia GeForce 6100 missing memory

Tags: nvidia, 13.10

I'm not hardware guru so I'm really lost here. I have Nvidia GeForce 6100 graphics card, which have 512 MB of RAM, but when I open NVidia settings I see:
Total memory: 512 MB
Total dedicated memory: 128 MB

So I can only use those 128 MB. Why is that so, can I increase dedicated memory

Comment: There are so many Nvideo GeForce 6100 cards from multiple manufacturers that the information you've provided isn't enough. Who was the card manufacturer?

Comment: I don't know who is manufacture, can't find that information in NVidia settings. Is there any other method to get that information

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing "128 MB dedicated memory" is that the kernel also reserves some normal system RAM for graphics on top of the graphics card's RAM. The 512 MB is being used.